# querySelector() return static node list or live node list

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

querySelectorALL() as specified by MDN donot support live nodes and return only static nodes.[MDN querySelectorALL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

Can querySelector()  support live node MDN donot specified anything about it[MDN querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Well since querySelector does not return a list, it's static. (it's a static reference to a Node)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a static **list** (specifically, a static [`NodeList`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist)), whereas (say) `getElementsByTagName` returns a *live* **list** (specifically, a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection)).¹ It's the **list** that's static or live, not the nodes/elements on the list.

An element returned by `querySelector` is the element in the DOM (as are the elements in the list from `querySelectorAll`). They're "live," not snapshots or clones — e.g., if they're changed, you can see those changes via the reference you have from `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll`.

Example:

```js
const element = document.querySelector("input");
const staticList = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const liveList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

element.addEventListener("input", () => {
  // Both of these are references to the live node in the DOM
  console.log(element.value);
  console.log(staticList[0].value);
});

document.getElementById("del").addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Removing the input
  document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector("input"));
  // It's still on the static list
  console.log("staticList.length = " + staticList.length); // 1
  // It's off the live list now
  console.log("liveList.length = " + liveList.length); // 0
  // Since we still have a reference to it, we can still see it's value
  console.log(element.value); // "what you typed"
});
```

```html
Type something: <input type="text">
<br>then click this: <button id="del" type="button">Delete</button>
```

---

¹ `HTMLCollection` instances are always live.² `NodeList` instances may be either live or static (snapshots). The `NodeList` you get from `querySelectorAll` is static, but the `NodeList` you get from (say) the `childNodes` property of an `Element` is live. Here's an example of that:

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");

console.log(`Get a static list of the container's elements`);
const list = container.querySelectorAll("*");
console.log(`It's a NodeList:`);
console.log(list.constructor.name); // "NodeList"
console.log(`With one element in it:`);
console.log(list.length); // 1

console.log(`Get a live list of children`);
const children = container.childNodes;
console.log(`It's also a NodeList:`);
console.log(children.constructor.name); // "NodeList"
console.log(`With one element in it (so far):`);
console.log(children.length); // 1

console.log(`Add a new child`);
const p = document.createElement("p");
container.appendChild(p);

console.log(`The static list still has one element:`);
console.log(list.length); // 1
console.log(`But the live list has two:`);
console.log(children.length); // 2
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><p></p></div>
```

² *"`HTMLCollection` instances are always live."* - Actually, the specification doesn't say that. I base that statement on two things:

1. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) says that (but MDN, while very high-quality, isn't always 100% correct).
2. All the current `HTMLCollection` instances the specification describes are live, and no new `HTMLCollection` instances will be added in the future; it's a legacy type. If any new collections are added, they'll be defined either as [`Sequence<T>`](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-sequence) instances or as `NodeList` instances.